# Goodness of fit metric to compare topic models NMF vs LDA

Tags: topic-model, lda, model-selection

Does anyone have a good idea for how to compare topic modeling done by NMF and LDA? Let's say I fit LDA to a dataset and generate topic-word and document-topic distributions--I can use perplexity, for instance, to measure the goodness of fit of the model. If I fit NMF to the same dataset and generate topic-word and document-topic distributions, I can take the resultant fitted data as $X^{Est} = HW^T$ and use $\|X^{Original} - X^{Est}\|_{Fro}$ as a goodness of fit of the model.

What is an objective metric that I can use to compare the goodness of fits to each other? Can either of these metrics be used for the other model?

Comment: http://qpleple.com/perplexity-to-evaluate-topic-models/

Answer (score 3):

NMF and LDA models produce topic-word and document-topic distributions, so you can compare these models on evaluation tasks of topic coherence (i.e. evaluating topic-word distributions), document clustering/classification (i.e. evaluating document-topic distributions) or information retrieval (i.e. evaluating topic-word and document-topic distributions together).

See some examples in "[Improving topic models with latent feature word representations](https://transacl.org/ojs/index.php/tacl/article/view/582/158)", "[LDA-Based Document Models for Ad-hoc Retrieval](https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/0ef3/11acf523d4d0e2cc5f747a6508af2c89c5f7.pdf)".

Comment: Thanks for the cursory - but useful - connection of `topic coherence` to topic-word,  `doc clustering/classification` to evaluation of doc-topic and `IR` to evaluation of topic-word and doc-topic together. I had not seen that presented before.